# Use Flutter Bloc one event resulted value in another event under the same bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Here i want to reuse ExpenseFetchList event result in ExpenseAdd event. I do not want to call API again. how i can do it under good practice.

```
     ExpenseBloc() : super(ExpenseInitial()) {
      on<ExpenseEvent>((ExpenseEvent event, Emitter<ExpenseState> emit) async {
      if (event is ExpenseFetchList) {
        emit(ExpenseFetching());
        List<Expense> e = dummyExpenseList; //await event.useCase.getAll();
        // TODO: remove Future.delayed
        // ignore: always_specify_types
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
          emit(ExpenseFetched(list: e));
        });
        return;
      }
      if (event is ExpenseAdd) {
        // Here i do not want to call API again
        // concatinate above event fetched values with this and return simply.
        return;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: From where are you calling the expenseAdd event is it from the list that you fetched.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add an optional variable for that API response in your parent state. For example its name is ExpenseState

```
abstract class ExpenseState {
  ExpenseState({required this.expenseResponse});

  final ExpenseResponseModel? expenseResponse;
}
```

After that, extend both of your states i.e ExpenseFetchList and ExpenseAdd will have access to the api response variable.

```
class ExpenseAdd extends ExpenseState { }

class ExpenseFetchList extends ExpenseState { }
```

Comment: Thank you Hassan, i want to call ExpenseFetchList and ExpenseAdd events independently. i need a variable that saves the API data and we can access this from all event actions. is this possible for us to create this in the base state class or bloc class?

Comment: i am from react-redux toolkit background, i want to do in flutter bloc as i do in redux, save response in state variable and access this from everywhere.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Let me edit my answer according to your needs

Comment: Thank you! Hassan, your answer gives me another way to resolve my problem.